# How to append properties to a generic type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to have additional properties added to a generic type. Here's what I have:

```
type RequestData<T> = {
   name: string,
   data: {
      [K in keyof T]: T[K],
      isActive: boolean     // Typescript is not happy with this
   }
}
```

Basically, my intention is to add the property `isActive` as one of the properties to the generic type of `T`. But Typescript is complaining about what I have done.

I want my eventual usage to be something like this:

```
type TestData = { item: any[] };

const myFunc = <T>() => {
    const myData: RequestData<T> = {
        name: 'test',
        data: {
            item: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            isActive: true,
        },
    };
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=18&ssc=11&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYARAhsTAeAKgHxQC8UA3gFBQ1QB2mAthAFxRoBOAlnQOYDc1WgBNsmNlVpSoAbQDSUHlADWEEAHsAZlHwBdNvnm7BUgL5QAZBSHTFKAIIBjYFwBurKACN16gDYRMOhNaU0FQykpQSB1UDDFSCkVgCEY2QJAZXShwykd1OjQoRhAAMUQ6RwSCQgAKAEpSYklaPILgIpAsHDY4JFiuvCIE5tsGZjYAcmS0CYAaG2lRbutbWy5k1NkJzDmoCc9diccJ3XnV6S4HZzcPYA5kM9XTR5pw0wigA)

How can I append additional properties to a generic type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it works

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=10&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYARAhsTAeAKgHxQC8UA3gFBQ1QB2mAthAFxRoBOAlnQOYDc1WgBNsmNlVpSoAbQDSUHlADWEEAHsAZlHwBdNvnm7BUgL5QAZBSHTFKAIIBjYFwBurKACN16gDYRMOhNaU0FQykpQSB1UDDFSCkVgCEY2QJAZXShwykd1OjQoRhAsHDY4JFjSvHwqsWIySVoGZjYAcmS0NoAaGyhRMutbGi5k1Nk2zB6oNs9ptsc23V7huycXdzZgDmQVkN7QoA)

```
type RequestData<T> = {
    name: string;
    data: {
        [K in keyof T]: T[K];
    } & {
        isActive: boolean;
    };
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the usage in my question. I think I still have problem when I use it in a function. Here's the playground code:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYARAhsTAeAKgHxQC8UA3gFBQ1QB2mAthAFxRoBOAlnQOYDc1WgBNsmNlVpSoAbQDSUHlADWEEAHsAZlHwBdNvnm7BUgL5QAZBSHTFKAIIBjYFwBurKACN16gDYRMOhNaU0FQykpQSB1UDDFSCkVgCEY2QJAZXShwykd1OjQoRhAAMUQ6RwSCQgAKAEpSYklaPILgIpAsHDY4JFiuvCIE5tsGZjYAcmS0CYAaG2lRbutbWy5k1NkJzDmoCc9diccJ3XnV6S4HZzcPYA5kM9XTR5pw0wigA

Comment: @Carven Your function `myFunc` don't know about field `item`, it is error another type :)